# Caching images with same name different directory

Tags: php, caching

On my server I have multiple folders with different names. Each folder contains an image "data.png". Will the browser cache images of different folders separately even though the name is same? Does it use URL instead of image names?

Comment: im assuming it varies from browser to browser, but if it caches it then its probably based on the path

Comment: This is something you can test quite easily. Have a server with such a setup and check how your browser handles loading those images by inspecting the network tab in the developer tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Will the browser cache images of different folders separately 
even though the name is same?
```

Yes. Images in cache are URL contingent.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide any references to prove your answer?